# desktop application / script to interact with javascript on web application

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, web-applications

My work has tasked me with determining the feasibility of migrating our existing in-house built change management services(web based) to a Sharepoint solution. I've found everything to be easy except I've run into the issue that for each change management issue (several thousand) there may be any number of attachment files associated with them, called through javascript, that need to be downloaded and put into a document library.

*(ex. ... onClick="DownloadAttachment(XXXXX,'ProjectID=YYYY');return false">Attachment... ).*

To keep me from manually selecting them all I've been looking over posts of people wanting to do similar, and there seem to be many possible solutions, but they often seem more complicated than they need to be.

So I suppose in a nutshell I'm asking what would be the best way to approach this issue that yields some sort of desktop application or script that can interact with web pages and will let me select and organize all the attachments.  (Making a purely web based app (php, javascript, rails, etc.) is not an option for me, so throwing that out there now).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the onclick="DownloadAttachment(xxxxx,'ProjectID=yyyy')... was just to show I was dealing with a javascript method and not a direct link to the files needed. 

To expand on the first part of my issue: 
The project ID I know (there are 3 Im dealing with) and the individual issue IDs I can generate a report with all the numbers of, which can then be used in url to go to each issue's page. The problem is that on each of these pages there may or may not be any number of links to attachments (the javascript download method) with arbitrary number IDs.

Comment: And after inspecting the javascript "DownloadAttachment()" function (By the way, I just discovered the built in chrome dev tools = amazing) I can assemble a url for each attachment link. So I suppose I need a way to go to pages, inspect their source, and if a download link exists, construct a URL for it, save the attachment, and move on to the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I was able to get what I needed using htmlunit and java to traverse a report I made of all change items with attachments, go to each one, copy the source code, traverse that to find instances of the download method, and copy the unique IDs of each attachment and build an .xls of all items and their attachments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Given a document id and project id,
   `XXXXX` and `YYYY` respectively in
   your example, figure out the URL
   from which the file contents can be
   downloaded. You can observe a few
   URL links in the browser and detect
   the pattern which your web
   application uses.
2. Use a tool like Selenium to get a
   list of `XXXXX`s and `YYYY`s of
   documents you need to download.
3. Write a bash script with wget to
   download the files locally and put
   in the correct folders.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "one off" migration, right?

1. Get access to your in-house application's database, and create an SQL query which pulls out rows showing the attachment names (`XXXXX`?) and the issue/project (`YYYY`?), ex:

   ```
   |file_id|issue_id|file_name           |  
   |      5|     123|Feasibility Test.xls|
   ```
2. Analyze the `DownloadAttachment` method and figure out how it generates the URL that it calls for each download.
3. Start a script (personally I'd go for Python) that will do the migration work.
4. Program the script to connect and run the SQL query, or can read a CSV file you create manually from step #1.
5. Program the script to use the details to determine the target-filename and the URL to download from.
6. Program the script to download the file from the given URL, and place it on the hard drive with the proper name. (In Python, you might use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).)

Hopefully that will get you as far as a bunch of files categorized by "issue" like:

```
issue123/Feasibility Test.xls
issue123/Billing Invoice.doc
issue456/Feasibility Test.xls
```